# Add Oauth2 in a node js script using the ArcGIS js SDK

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, esri, arcgis-js-api

I have the following node script which successfully accesses a public webmap in ArcGIS online:

```
import WebMap from '@arcgis/core/WebMap.js';
import esriConfig from "@arcgis/core/config.js";

esriConfig.request.useIdentity = false;

const webmap = new WebMap({
  portalItem: { id: "3d52817a120b477db912add2e62ef9b6" }
});

webmap.load()
    .then(() => {
        console.log(webmap.portalItem.description);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

I'd like to add Oauth2 to that so I can access restricted content, although I'm not sure if that is possible with a server side node script.